# Django Admin --Bulk Staff User Creation/Import from CSV file

Tags: python, django, admin, user-defined-functions

I have a question. I have to import all of the users that will be allowed in my Django Admin app from an excel/csv file. Can someone please advice, guide me how i can implement this thing in Django Admin Interface. There is a script i can use? All of them will be allowed to login to my Django app and all of them will be automatically made staff users.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Why not just `open` the file and `for` loop through it initializing and saving `User` models as you go or use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create?

Comment: i was not able to find something in the docs. seen a 3rd party plugin but is for models, was not able to see something for the Django Default User creation part.

Comment: When you create a user you can set `is_staff` to `True` like `User(..., is_staff=True) or using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#manager-methods

Comment: you might give this a try : https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export

Answer (score 7):

So for those that will be in my shoes, please see bellow what did the trick!

```
import csv, sys, os, django


project_dir = "/parcare/src/"
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'adp_parking.settings'
# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", __file__)
import django
django.setup()


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings
User = get_user_model()

file = 'import.csv'

data = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=",")
for row in data:
    if row[0] != "Number":
        # Post.id = row[0]
        Post=User()
        Post.password = row[1]
        Post.last_login = "2018-09-27 05:51:42.521991"
        Post.is_superuser = "0"
        Post.username = row[2]
        Post.first_name = row[3]
        Post.email = row[4]
        Post.is_staff = "1"
        Post.is_active = "1"
        Post.date_joined = "2018-09-27 05:14:50"
        Post.last_name=row[5]
        Post.save()
```

This is how my import.csv file looks like

[image]

And they were added on top of what i had out there
[image]

Now the single step is to give permissions to all of them.
Only the second record which is non admin has the rights.

[image]

PS Add a hashed pass, without it, the user will not work. So you have to create a test pass, and use that hash inserted into the pass row field==>and this will work like a charm.

Comment: You wont be able to login by setting the password this way. You need to wrap it in the from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password  make_password function.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from csv import reader
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def userdata(request):
with open('templates/csv/your_file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csvf = reader(csv_file)
    data = []
    for username, password, *__ in csvf:
        user = User(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        data.append(user)
    User.objects.bulk_create(data)
    
return JsonResponse('user csv is now working', safe=False)
```

### then in your urls.py

path('userdata/', userdata, name='userdata')

##just redirect to the url and all the data will be pushed to the database